# reassigning to const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

With pointers I can do this:

```
int a=1;
int b=2;

const int* cnstIntPtr = &a;
// (*cnstIntPtr)++ does not work, makes sense since value pointed to is constant
cnstIntPtr = &b; // works, makes sense

const int* const cnstIntCnstPtr  = &a;
// (*cnstIntCnstPtr)++; does not work, makes sense since value pointed to is constant
// cnstIntCnstPtr = &b;  does not work, makes sense since pointer is constant
```

but with references:

```
const int& cnstIntRef = a;
// cnstIntRef++; does not work, makes sense since const refers to value at address
// cnstIntRef = b; why does this not work? "expression must be modifiable lvalue"

const int& const cnstIntCnstRef = a;
//cnstIntCnstRef++; does not work, makes sense since const refers to value at address
//cnstIntCnstRef = b; does not work, makes sense since const refers to value at address
```

So why can't I reassign to a const reference when the const is supposed to be referring to the value at the address (by analogy with how pointers work). If this is in general not possible, why is that and what is the meaning of the second const in

`const int& const cnstIntCnstRef`?

Comment: There is no way to rebind a reference. Once initialized to refer to an object, it will refer to that object throughout its lifetime. The second `const` in `const int& const cnstIntCnstRef` is redundant.

Comment: What Igor said.  In other words, when you write "cnstIntCnstRef = b;" you are attempting to change the refer*ent*:  The thing being referred *to*, (also known as "a").  But that's not allowed since it is declared as const.  And you are certainly not allowed to make the reference refer to something else (like, say, "b").

Comment: If you want to reassign a reference, use `std::reference_wrapper`. Note that it's used mostly for generic code and forwarding purposes.

Comment: Then how do I deal with a std::vector<const int&> in an initialization list? What I need to do is set the size of it, and later in the constructor body fill in the elements. Unfortunately, push_back is out of the question since it messes up the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // cnstIntRef = b; why does this not work? "expression must be modifiable lvalue"
> ```

For the same reason as why `cnstIntRef++;` doesn't work. `cnstIntRef` is reference to const, and therefore the the value may not be assigned to.

> If this is in general not possible, why is that

It is indeed not possible.

References are different from pointers: They are dereferenced automatically. An assignment to a reference variable is an assignment to the referred object. Just as you understand that `cnstIntRef++` is analogous to `(*cnstIntPtr)++` , you must also understand that  `cnstIntRef = a` is analogous to `*cnstIntPtr = a`.

As a consequence, there is no syntax to "reassign" a reference to refer to another object. A reference always refers to exactly one object throughout its entire lifetime.

---

> what is the meaning of the second const in
>
> ```
> const int& const cnstIntCnstRef?
> ```

It has no meaning because it is ill-formed. Unlike to pointers, qualifiers may not be applied to references; they may only be applied to the referred type.

---

> then how do I deal with a `std::vector<const int&>`

You cannot deal with `std::vector<const int&>` because `const int&` is not a valid type for an element of `std::vector`. Vector requires the elements to be erasable. References are not erasable.

> What I need to do is set the size of it, and later in the constructor body fill in the elements.

You can use a vector of pointers instead. Or vector of `std::reference_wrapper` if that's more convenient for template purposes.

> push_back is out of the question since it messes up the references

`push_back` won't mess up references if you `reserve` first.